# AWS CodeBuild Webhook in aws-cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-cdk

What is the best way to create an AWS CodeBuild Project with a GitHub Webhook for running checks on Pull Requests using the `aws-cdk`?

Answer (score 5):

<strike>Unfortunately, as of writing this (December 2018), this functionality is not supported through CloudFormation (see AWS forum post [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=273576)).</strike>

<strike>Because the CDK uses CloudFormation behind the scenes to perform deployments, if something is not supported in CloudFormation, we also can't support it in the CDK.</strike>

**EDIT**: I was actually wrong. While the `branchFilter` attribute that you see in the AWS Console for CodeBuild is not supported in CloudFormation, the webhook itself is.

Example code of creating a webhook with the CDK (in TypeScript):

```
import codebuild = require('@aws-cdk/aws-codebuild');
import cdk = require('@aws-cdk/cdk');

const project = new codebuild.Project(this, 'MyProject', {
  source: new codebuild.GitHubSource({
    owner: 'awslabs',
    repo: 'aws-cdk',
    oauthToken: new cdk.SecretParameter(this, 'GitHubOAuthToken', {
      ssmParameter: 'my-github-token',
    }),
    webhook: true, // default: false
  }),
  // remaining Project parameters here...
});
```

Note that you need CDK version `0.21.0` or later for this functionality to be present.

Comment: Thank you @Adam. This is very helpful!